# How to calculate size of Windows bitmap font using FreeType

Tags: windows, fonts, freetype

## The Problem

I am loading the classic **serife.fon** file from Microsoft Windows using FreeType.

Here is how I set the size:

```
FT_Set_Pixel_Sizes(face, 0, fontHeight);
```

I use 0 for the `fontWidth` so that it will be auto-calculated based on the height.

**How do I find the correct value for `fontHeight` such that the resulting font will be exactly 9 pixels tall?**

---

### Notes

Using trial and error, I know that the correct value is 32 - but I don't understand why.

I am not sure how relevant this is for bitmap fonts, but according to [the docs](https://www.freetype.org/freetype2/docs/glyphs/glyphs-2.html):

```
pixel_size = point_size * resolution / 72
```

Substituting in the values:

```
point_size = 32
resolution = 96 (from FT_Get_WinFNT_Header)
```

gives:

```
pixel_size = 42.6666666
```

This is a long way from our target height of 9!

The docs do go on to say:

> `pixel_size` computed in the above formula does not directly relate to the size of characters on the screen. It simply is the size of the EM square if it was to be displayed. Each font designer is free to place its glyphs as it pleases him within the square.

But again, I am not sure if this is relevant for bitmap fonts.

Answer (score 0):

`fon` files are exe files with a `fnt` payload, where the `fnt` payload can be a vector or raster font. If this is a raster font (which is most likely) then the `dfPixHeight` value in the fnt header will tell you what size it's meant to be, which is exposed by FreeType2 as the `pixel_height` field of the `FT_WinFNT_Header`.

(And of course, note that using any size other than "the actual raster-size of the FNT" is going to lead to hilarious headaches because bitmap scaling is the kind of madness that's so bad, OpenType instead went with "just embed as many bitmaps as you need, at however many sizes you need, because that's the only way your bitmaps are going to look good")

The FNT-specific FT2 documentation can be found over on https://www.freetype.org/freetype2/docs/reference/ft2-winfnt_fonts.html but you may need to read it in conjunction with https://jeffpar.github.io/kbarchive/kb/065/Q65123 (or https://web.archive.org/web/20120215123301/http://support.microsoft.com/kb/65123) to find any further mappings that you might need between names/fields as defined in the FNT spec and FT2's naming conventions.

Comment: This is indeed a raster font. The `pixel_height` field for this font is 13. But using 13 as the `fontHeight` results in the font being rendered so small that it's completely unreadable.

Comment: you may want to show some [mcve] code in your post in that case, because FT2 should just rasterize the glyphs at their true size. Also, for font-related questions, you definitely want to also ask things like this over on https://typedrawers.com, where all the font folks hang out.

Comment: (you may also want to mention whether you're using a "normal" display or a "retina" or other high-dpi display, because 13 true pixels without compensating for the pixel density of a retina display effectively renders as the equivalent of 6.5 pixels or smaller on a traditional screen)